# Gzip compression to html website through PHP

Tags: gzip

my website is in html and i want to enable gzip compression, my server has provided gzip compression through PHAR extension.

can you guide me how to do gzip .

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to enable GZIP in the .htaccess, assuming your host allows you to change/add an .htaccess file. If they do, I write about [how to enable GZIP](http://salscode.com/web-resources/gzip-htaccess):

```
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
```